# PDO Query failing to update but returning success

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, pdo, sql-update

Based on the code I have below I am trying to make an SQL query that would look like the following:

```
update support_term set units_dk=$value['machines'] where support_acct='$key' and term_id=$term;
```

Here is the PDO statement I am using to try and make this sql update:

```
 foreach($data as $key => $value) {
            $setAccounts = $conn->prepare('UPDATE '.STERM_T.' SET units_dk=? WHERE support_acct=? and term_id=?');
            $setAccounts->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $setAccounts->bindParam(1, $value['machines']);
            $setAccounts->bindParam(2, $key);
            $setAccounts->bindParam(3, $term);
            echo 'Machines:' . $value['machines'] . '. Key:' . $key . '. Term:' . $term . PHP_EOL;
            if(!is_null($key) || $key != '') {
                $setAccounts->execute();
            }
        }
```

The updates are returning as successes however I do not see the associated records being updated. Looking at what I have echo'd out here is what is shows:

```
Machines:38. Key:sc-ai. Term:1145
```

Based on this I constructed a SQL update:

```
update support_term set units_dk=38 where support_acct='sc-ai' and term_id=1145;
select term_id,support_acct,units_dk from support_term where support_acct='sc-ai' and term_id=1145;
```

Results:

[image: results]

So as you can see the update worked. So why is it not updating any records when done via PDO?

Comment: Is this constant correctly defined? `STERM_T`

Comment: How do you determine that "the updates are returning as successes"?

Comment: Also did you check for `$conn->errorInfo()` ?

Comment: Does this help: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php#98145 ? Btw, if you don't use XDebug or something like that to debug, you can usually get better debug values by using var_dump($val) (3 times) instead of echo.

Comment: @pritaeas the sql query returns true. So what I mean is that it is returning a "success".

Comment: @MartijnHols I know my data that it is given is correct, it is the PDO statement that has a problem.

Comment: @MartijnHols trying what the user said did not fix the issue :(.

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky this may be the issue actually. I am running from the command line this code and it is different than the web stuff and this may actually be failing. I will investigate.

Comment: Why not simply remove that and put the actual table name there inside the string?

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky no I mean the $conn may be the issue. The constant is fine.

Comment: Yep $conn absolutely has to be there, checking for errorInfo will help

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky it looks like it was an issue with the connection not being made. This fixed the problem.